# React: How to update the display of a state variable with delay and animation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently learning react a bit and wondering which are the "most react" ways to add a delay and animation to the update of a component triggered by a state update of the parent.

The situation is as follows:
I have a state variable that is updated whenever the user interacts with the website in a certain way. There is a component that displays a quantity which is derived from that state variable.

Rather than an immediate update, I would like to achieve (e.g.) the following: After the interaction, the content of the display component at first stays as is (i.e. shows the old value), but transitions to opacity 0, say over .5 seconds. Then, the content is updated to the new value, and opacity transitions back to 1.

I suspect that this could be done using `useEffect` somehow (at least that should give me convenient access to the old value). However, I can't think of a clean way to achieve delay and transition in a way that feels like it should be done in react (as opposed to, e.g., just injecting  some hand-coded javascript function that does the transitions by directly referencing the DOM element or so.)

Below is a minimal example of the situation at hand. `number` is of course the state that's updated by user interaction, and `DisplayNumber` the derived component that should change in the delayed manner.

```js
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

export default function App(){

    const [number, setNumber] = useState(0)

    function handleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        const form = e.target;
        const formData = new FormData(form);
        const formJson = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries());
            setNumber(formJson.number);
    }

    return (
        <div className='App'>
            <form method='post'  onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                New number: <input type='number' name='number' defaultValue={0}/>
                <button type='submit'>update</button>
            </form>
            <h2>Current number is: <DisplayNumber number={number}/> </h2>
        </div>
    );
}

function DisplayNumber({number}) {
    return <span className='number'>{number}</span>
}
```

Comment: do you mean to use with settimeout?

Comment: You could use a `useRef` to track the old number and transition state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to acheive this is by using the `useEffect` hook along with the `useRef` hook to store the previous value and CSS transitions for the `opacity`. A small sample will look like:

```js
function DisplayNumber({ number }) {
  const [displayNumber, setDisplayNumber] = useState(number);
  // state variable for controlling opacity
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(true);
  const prevNumber = useRef(number);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Basically when number prop changes, 
   // isVisible is set to false and opacity transition begins.
    if (number !== prevNumber.current) {
      setIsVisible(false);
      setTimeout(() => {
        prevNumber.current = number;
        setDisplayNumber(number);
        // which is set to true after 0.5s thereby completing opacity transition. 
        setIsVisible(true);
      }, 500);
    }
  }, [number]);

  return (
    <span
      className="number"
      style={{
        transition: "opacity 0.5s",
        opacity: isVisible ? 1 : 0,
      }}
    >
      {displayNumber}
    </span>
  );
}
```

***[SAMPLE DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/focused-kirch-yq75qy?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A22%2C20)***